# How are you testing configuration changes?

Tags: automated-testing, testing-environment, configuration-testing

I am curious if folks are testing configuration changes in applications. For example, I have a Spring Boot app that pulls its configurations from a local properties file at build time and from Spring Cloud Config Server at runtime. When I deploy this app to a non-prod environment, it will have different configurations than when I deploy it to production. As a result, while the artifact I'm testing in non-prod is the same as the one I deploy to production, its configurations will be different.

My question is...how do you *test* these configuration changes? That is, how do you verify functionality of the app when configurations change. Health checks to service and db URLs could be run after a production deploy, but is there a way to test these in a lower environment?

Besides the above example, is anyone testing other configuration changes in lower environments to make sure deploys to production are successful?

I've tried to find information on this subject, but "configuration testing" typically has a different meaning in the quality engineering world.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change the config in the non-prod environment as to your needs for testing? Configuration could/should be easy to change, so change it to the prod value, and test what you need.

Is there somethnig deeper I don't get from your question? I don't know, but the general principle is you need to be able to control things in order to test, which seems to be possible with configuration.